# How to make function to call only when input parameters are change

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating set of user defined functions, but I only need to recall these function if and only a input parameter of a partcular function is change.

Currently, even I delete/insert a row the function are being called, How can I stop this function recalling ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can work around it by remembering the parameters that were passed to your function. You can use some global variable (an array) where you record the parameters. 
However, it does not sound very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Save the parameter(s) to Static variable(s) and exit the sub if the parameters haven't changed.